# How may I access to a twig variable with innerHTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twig

I'm currently trying to to get an innerHTML from a twig variable using javascript. But I cannot access to it.

I created a calendar which is an array. And I pass it through my controller so I can use it with twig in my template.
Then I named a div where I render some cells from this array.
Using javascript I get the id from my div and use innerHTML method.
After that, I simply add a alertbox to check if my innerHTML is showed.

***myPage.html.twig***:

```
{% for day in calendrier %}
....
<div id="myId">{{day[2]}}</div>
...
{% endfor %}
```

***javascript.js:***

```
document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener('click', fn);

function fn(){ alert(this.innerHTML); };
```

I cannot access to this value.
I expected to get the day from this div. Let's say for example '14' or any number the user click on the calendar.

How may I process to reach `{{ day[2] }}` ?

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: ID in HTML must be unique, that is why it is not working. Please use classes or add indexes to your IDs

Comment: What does "I cannot access this value mean"? What does your alert display? Is it the value of the first item in the iteration?

Comment: Ok thank you Damian, i will try it.